# Js google calenddar api add event insert wrong time

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-calendar-api

I try to insert event to calendar:

```
var timeZone=Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;
                var resource = {
                    "summary": summary,
                    "location": "",
                    "start": {
                        "dateTime": "2017-12-24T03:00:00",
                        "timeZone":timeZone
                    },
                    "end": {
                        "dateTime": "2017-12-24T04:00:00",
                        "timeZone":timeZone

                    }
                };
 var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.insert({
                    'calendarId': 'primary',
                    'resource': resource
                });
                request.execute(function(resp) {
                    console.log(resp);
                });
```

But when I run this  I have event in my calendar,but its time is wrong. Start is at 5:00:00 and end is at 6:00:00 . How can I solve it? Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you use a different timezone?

Comment: I also have wrong event data

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the value of the request with timezone and the result?